# Objective-C Swift interoperability with Realm

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I'm adding new functionality to an app written in Objective-C with Swift. The new features require a data base so I'm using Realm-Swift. The problem is that the models that have relationships e.g. `dynamic var points = List<Point>()` don't translate to Objective-C on the `{Project}-Swift.h` file. I get the error: `Type name requires a specifier or qualifier` on the line `@property (nonatomic) /* List<Point> */ points;`

Does anybody know a workaround for this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need Objective-C interop, your best bet is to continue using Realm Objective-c. Since `List` is a generic type, it can't be represented in ObjC at all.

Comment: is absolutely right. I updated the text at the top of our [Swift](http://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/) and [Objective-C](http://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/) docs to clarify this a bit.